# (Hortonworks Sandbox) Pig Join operation duplicate primary key columns

Tags: join, duplicates, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I have two tables that I want to join.
table1 has **id** and **value** columns.
table2 has **id** and **color** columns.

```
final = join table1 by id, table2 by id;
dump final;
```

I received table whose columns are **id**, **value**, **id**, **color**. But I want to obtain a table which has columns like **id**, **value** and **color**. How can I remove this duplicate id column from this table?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `DESCRIBE final;` you will see that the schema looks something like this:

```
final: {table1::id: chararray,table1::value: chararray,table2::id: chararray,table2::color: chararray}
```

To distinguish between the two ID columns, you can use `table1::id` or `table2::id`. So to remove one of the duplicate columns, you can do:

```
A = FOREACH final GENERATE 
    table1::id AS id,
    table1::value AS value,
    table2::color AS color;
```

(I've also renamed the fields to get rid of the `table1::` and `table2::` prefixes since they're no longer necessary.)

I could have also done:

```
A = FOREACH final GENERATE 
    table1::id AS id,
    value AS value,
    color AS color;
```

This would not have given me an error since `value` and `color` are unambiguous names.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your final PIG script:

```
grunt> table1 = LOAD 'table1_input_path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, value:int);
grunt> table2= LOAD 'table2_input_path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, color:chararray);
grunt> joinlevel = JOIN table1 BY id, table2 BY id;
grunt> final = FOREACH joinlevel generate table1::id as id, table1::color as color, table2::value as value;
grunt> dump final;
```